# Roots Theme 6.4 Disappearing Homepage Content with decreasing screen size

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, media-queries

Good Day,

I have noticed today that for some reason using WordPress 3.6.1 and Roots 6.4.0 that the homepage had blank content between the footer and the logo. However, it only happens on the homepage, works fine on any other page, and it has only happened recently.

You may check out the website: http://jsteinhi.com.

I ask that someone please check it out, and tell me if this a media query problem, CSS, PHP, or WordPress problem. I want to know, so I can avoid this happening again if it was a mistake I made that or changes to a post that caused this.

I thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly the problem lied with a "display: none" in my main stylesheet. Don't know why it was there under a media query, but it's now fixed.